# Assertion by an answers.microsoft.com moderator that SO is an "MS forum"

Tags: discussion

I got myself slightly suckered into a conversation on Answers.microsoft.com about some of their more frustrating practices. One of their moderators responded with this (which I am 99.99% sure isn't true):

> In case you dont know Stack overflow & Super user are MS forums.

Then when challenged, the moderator replied:

> Um no, it is not "a completely independent entity".  It is an affiliated engaged site.  As you say there is no "contract" in place.  Would love to share the documentation with you but the stats are under NDA (non disclosure agreement)
>   Suffice it to say when a users stats are tabulated for MS sites SO/SU/SF are listed.
>   Think of them in the same manner as skype.  Different name same owner.

Had it been a random user saying so, I would have ignored it as a stupid comment, but being a moderator, I wanted to raise it here to get a real response.

I am reasonably confident that MS doesn't own SO though!

Oh yes, the [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/feedback/forum/fdbk_commsite-mods/attention-microsoft-support-engineers-moderators/94cfb1fc-f77a-43b4-96a7-842922f7b128?page=3).

Comment: I think the use of the word "forum" is evidence enough that they don't know what they're talking about.

Comment: Person is probably trolling. Or misunderstanding that just because MS collect stats about things that occur on Stack Exchange, it means there's a strong link there.

Comment: @TZHX that is very much my suspicion, but the person saying it seems to have some standing there, and I wanted to formulate a proper response (and probably point to this thread in doing so) rather than a knee jerk answer

Comment: He mentions he knows about some documentation which is under an NDA agreement, but signs off as `I do not work for MS` - which means he wouldn't be able to see these documents anyway, *if they were to even exist*.

Comment: @rob being under an nda is not limited to (or even primarily used for) employees.

Comment: @Rob MVPs are privvy to NDA information AFAIK. Though it looks like he got the wrong end of the stick here.

Comment: @TZHX I realise it's not only used for employees, but I would be skeptical if a forum moderator were given access to information about the inner workings of MS (at least to the detail requiring an NDA). Though MartinSmith says it's possible, so there ya go.

Comment: Tell him to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/company/about). MS is not even listed there.

Comment: It is just nonsense, you already know that.  He added 1+1 and ended up with 11 somehow.  Being a moderator at answers doesn't mean that much, there is nothing like a formal election procedure like we have here.  If you show up often enough and don't inflame too many people then Microsoft will make you one.  I am one (not at answers), shows you how easy it is :)  It is extra nonsense because nothing at answers would ever be on topic at SO.  Could fit SU.  Very hard to get rid of bad info, forum sites like this one were the primary motivation for starting SO 8 years ago.

Comment: Microsoft may sponsor some tags on SO/SU - but apart from that... nothing...(I'm not an SO employee but I feel 99.9r% confident in saying that :p)

Comment: "Think of them in the same manner as skype.  Different name same owner." lol!

Comment: aiiieee! Makes me want to remove the MVP designation from my user profile... What arrogance!

Comment: @MartinSmith I guess in the same way as moderators in the Stack Exchange network sign an NDA (*if I'm correct...*) for disclosure of private information.

Comment: Tell this person to post an answer here. We'll vote on their credibility. :)

Comment: @cybermonkey yup - you don't get your diamond until you agree to http://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara http://superuser.com/users/206180/zigzag3143 Last seen Dec 19 '15 at 11:15 ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill Too bad, they don't even have the rep to post here.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara He's got 34 on [su] is that enough? Or does he need rep on [so]?

Comment: @DavidPostill They would need 3 rep on SO to post on SO Meta (they have 1), and they don't have enough rep on SU for association bonus.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara That's a shame. I would love to see him engage here ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill Of course, a meager 2 rep points is easy enough to get. Just an accepted edit would get them that.

Comment: @DavidPostill he seems to have given up engaging even on the original thread so I doubt we'll see him here...

Comment: His byline includes a link to a description of the "Community Moderator" designation: "These are volunteers who are here to help the community. Community Moderators answer questions, and work to keep the community healthy and fun. Community moderators are members of the community, not Microsoft employees." While I'm sure this is frustrating, I'm not sure this is a concern for us here at SO.

Comment: "Suffice it to say when a users stats are tabulated for MS sites SO/SU/SF are listed." So if I scrape data from Stack Overflow, that makes me part owner? Sweet!

Comment: It really doesn't matter, Google owns Microsoft but I can't give the specifics because I'm under NDA. Trust me it's true! I'm the one guy on the internet you can trust!

Comment: This reminds me of the way Windows Explorer tells me (by default) that the type of all the HTML files on my computer is "Microsoft HTML Document".  Looks like they own me too!

Comment: April 1 is still a few days off. Thanks for ruining the joke Microsoft. :-(

Comment: @Rob: I'm not even an MVP and I don't even participate on Microsoft forums, but I too am bound by NDA on some super secret stuff (yes, I had to sign a document). So you don't even have to be an MVP, let alone a Microsoft employee, to be clued in on stuff they're working on.

Comment: Wouldn't the interaction by a considerable number of mods and 100k+ users make this unlikely to be off topic?

Comment: "I am reasonably confident that MS doesn't own SO though! " That's the crucial question here, isn't it? Maybe it does? Anyway, who is the current owner of "Stack Exchanges Inc."?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Microsoft has been slowly transitioning some of their larger developer communities to some of our sites - with some help from us. That the waves in which this happens go by without much notice is a pretty great compliment to folks on their end working to make sure people have a good experience.

I'm pretty sure this is just a case of informal internal speak manifesting publicly, e.g. "[SE site] is our place for that now" - at least that's probably how it *started*.

I'll look into reaching out to them. You know, as AT&T used to sing in their commercials that aired in North America some time ago ... *reach out, reach out and touch someone!*

**Update**

[I replied to the thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/feedback/forum/fdbk_commsite-mods/attention-microsoft-support-engineers-moderators/94cfb1fc-f77a-43b4-96a7-842922f7b128?page=4) to clear up any misconceptions or misinformation, better explain our relationship, and remind folks to be good to one another.

Comment: So, how much money (or securities) is/are changing hands in this relationship?

Comment: It's all transacted with tears of broken VB developers.

Comment: Damn! that's a big transaction!

Comment: @TimPost You must be sitting on rivers of salt water and mountains of dried salt then.

Comment: Almost five years later, the remote thread is still disturbing, and I don't think your response there managed to set the record straight. I'm sorry I clicked on that link.

Answer (score 46):

[image: Nope.]

> Think of them in the same manner as skype. Different name same owner.

Different name, *different* owner, actually.

Stack Overflow (the company) is not a subsidiary of Microsoft. The sites, including the trilogy, are owned and operated by Stack Overflow.

While I can't reason why the moderator said that, there may be a couple of reasons:

- S[OFUE] runs on a Microsoft stack (SQL Server, C# ASP.NET MVC)
- Microsoft sponsors a few tags on SO
- Microsoft collect a *lot* of stats; some of those are about S[OFUE]

Or, alternatively, the moderator you spoke to is sadly misguided (*forum*, really?) and needs some education.

Comment: Same mod is now saying _"Yawn. Believe what you like."_ He needs more than an education; a slap upside the head probably wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: As a onetime part of a company acquired by Microsoft, I am confident that Stack Exchange is independent.  There is a certain style (bloat/obfuscation) that MS ownership brings.  I see no evidence of that on Stack Overflow.  Things work too well here, for the most part.

Comment: Someone on the internet says something spectacularly wrong and stubbornly sticks to his guns against all sanity and reason. Shocking! I have never seen this happen before. And on the internet, of all places! I hope this doesn't turn into a new trend or something...

Comment: "Stack Overflow (the company) is not a subsidiary of Microsoft. The sites, including the trilogy, are owned and operated by Stack Overflow." This sounds a bit circular. Anyway, does anyone know who is the current owner of "StackExchanges Inc."?

Comment: @Trilarion http://stackoverflow.com/company/about

Comment: @Trilarion Stack Exchange, Inc. *is* the owner. It's its own company.

Comment: @nikoshr There seems to be only hints. Some institutional investors. But who owns how much? And is this list exhaustive? And is maybe MS behind one of them? I can only conclude that the ownership of SO is not known and there all people here say is mostly speculation.

Comment: @ArtOfCode So, who is the current owner of "StackExchanges Inc."? A company is just a tool. It must have an owner. Being it's own company doesn't make much sense or does it?

Comment: @Trilarion Stack Exchange, Inc. is the top level. I guess you could say it's *owned* by Joel Spolsky, who is the CEO.

Comment: @ArtOfCode CEO usually is not the same as owner. The comment by nikoshr hints that there are 70 million dollars invested in StackExchange Inc. so far by several institutional investors. I doubt they all belong to Joel Spolsky.

Comment: @Trilarion Correct, but "investors" != "owners"

Comment: @ArtOfCode Are you sure? Usually investors want something in return. Usually it's ownership although sometimes it's also only interest. Do you have any proof or sources that Joel Spolsky has currently complete control/rights of StackExchange Inc.? I think it is rather unlikely by now.

Comment: @Trilarion Go read Tim's response to the original thread on Answers. "Stack Overflow is a privately-held company".

Comment: @ArtOfCode You're right. That's what he says. So an unknown group of individuals (most probably among them Joel Spolsky) owns StackExchange Inc. Good source.

Answer (score 27):

I was all ready to build up a head of righteous indignation steam, until I realized *you're not talking about an SE moderator.*

All bets are off.

Every new user that comes to the SE network has to be educated about how it works, and why we're different from other Internet forums.  Microsoft Forum moderators are no different, in that regard.

That someone from *Microsoft* has misconceptions about Stack Exchange is just *par for the course.*

Comment: My concern, and only real reason for posting this, was that if a high rep moderator here made an equally bizarre assertion about some other site, members of this site would regard it as fact simply by virtue of their reputation. It seemed like too big of a statement to let lie and accumulate momentum, and as a random member here and there, my refuting it wouldn't have had any weight. Although I must say I have perhaps enjoyed the replies since!

Comment: The chances of that happening are pretty close to zero.  By the time SE mods get through the vetting process of an election, they all have a fair idea exactly what SE is, if they didn't already.

Comment: Not someone "from Microsoft" any more than you are from Stack Exchange, Inc., though. Just an unelected mod.

Comment: The problem is more that someone "from _Microsoft_" (fsvo 'from', as explored in other comments) has misconceptions about Microsoft itself.

Comment: To be honest I find it extremely unlikely that a SE mod would do something like that (in any case). We generally speaking don't elect people who like to talk BS or who can't stop talking when they know nothing.

Answer (score 5):

What a mind-bogglingly uninformed moderator on Microsoft forums that is:

> In case you don't know, Stack Overflow & Super User are MS forums.

There are two things wrong here:

- Neither Stack Overflow nor Super User are forums
- Neither are affiliated with Microsoft

> Um no, it is not "a completely independent entity".

It is

> It is an affiliated engaged site.

Despite that term being ambiguously defined, that's in no way true. IIRC Stack Exchange has no marketing deals with Microsoft to turn this into a Microsoft forum.

> Would love to share the documentation with you but the stats are under
>   NDA (non disclosure agreement)

That's either a blatant lie (if such a thing existed a random mod on Microsoft answers wouldn't know it does) or hilarious levels of misinformation.

> Think of them in the same manner as Skype. Different name, same owner.

That's completely absurd. Pretty hilarious that a moderator in the Microsoft forums doesn't know who owns Stack Exchange and who doesn't.

BTW, when confronted about his completely ridiculous statements, he likes to get condescending:

[image]

In conclusion, this (irrelevant) moderator on answer.ms has no idea what he is talking about and is probably just talking out of his feces exit channel directly.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - Doesn't fixing a quote make the quote inaccurate?